# Setting the lifecycle rule in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set the Life cycle rule for my existing bucket in aws. Below is the code that I am using:

```
 IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
          
            LifecycleConfiguration newConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration
            {
                Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
                    {
                       
                        new LifecycleRule
                        {
                            Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration  { Days = 2 },
                          
                        }
                    }
            };

            PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest putRequest = new PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest
            {
                BucketName = "test-bucket",
                Configuration = newConfiguration
            };
            client.PutLifecycleConfiguration(putRequest);
```

when I run the above code, I keep getting an error saying :

```
Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: 'The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema'
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I am very new to aws.

Any help will be higly appreciated.

Comment: any help with above question will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like S3 Lifecycle Configuration expects a prefix in [PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest.htm). So modifying your request to include a prefix like below should work for you.

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
            var lifecycleConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration
            {
                Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
                    {
                        new LifecycleRule
                        {
                            Filter = new LifecycleFilter
                                 {
                                     LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecyclePrefixPredicate
                                     {
                                         Prefix = "someprefix/"
                                     }
                                 },
                            Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration  { Days = 2 }
                        }
                    }
            };

            var putLifecycleConfigurationRequest = new PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest
            {
                BucketName = "bucketName",
                Configuration = lifecycleConfiguration
            };
            await client.PutLifecycleConfigurationAsync(putLifecycleConfigurationRequest);
```

Lifecycle rule created above will be disabled by default. Which can be enabled by setting `Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled` for LifecycleRule in the request.

And in case if you want the rule to be applicable for entire bucket, you can set the prefix to empty.

Edit : Even though the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_LifecycleRule.html) mentions the filter as optional, I suspect the [note](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html#object-key-xml-related-constraints) mentioned for [LifecycleRuleFilter Prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_LifecycleRuleFilter.html) might be the reason for XML error. (maybe the default value for the prefix has some issues and hence throws the XML error mentioned in the question)

Comment: I tried prefix before posting the question,. I am getting a warning saying that LifeCycleRule.prefix is obsolete. This property is obsolete. use the filter property instead. I tried using the filter property, but could not figure out how to use it. I